# How to automatically initialize the DB schema, on a spring boot + eclipselink + postgresql integration testing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to set up an integration testing framework for my Java 11, spring boot + eclipselink + postgresql application.
I use docker-maven-plugin to spin off a new postgresql DB container each time, and I'm running the integration tests using maven-failsafe-plugin. All good with this approach, except for the DB schema initialization: I'm not able to initialize that schema.

This is how my application-it.yaml looks like:

```
# Graceful shutdown delay            
application:
  shutdownhook:
    delay-msec: 500

# Spring Boot management endpoint configuration           
management:
  port: 9199
  info:
    git:
      mode: full
      
# Spring Boot enpoints Management endpoint        
endpoints:
  metrics:
    sensitive: false
  env:
    sensitive: false
  health:
    enabled: false

# short value just for testing 
estaGracefulShutdownWaitSeconds: 5

# Application-specific configuration
sample-application:
  server-name: Sample App Under Test

logging:
  config: classpath:log4j2-spring.xml

spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgresql
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:${it-database.port}/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    schema: classpath:schema-it.sql
    data: classpath:data-it.sql
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    initialization-mode: always
```

The schema-it.sql and data-it.sql are ok and available in the class path. There are no errors reported on their execution during the IT run. But still the schema doesn't get created (I know that because first the IT test are failing complain that the task table is missing and I'm able to access that test DB and i can see there are no table created in there).

The unit test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@SpringBootTest
public class TaskRepositoryIT {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetTasks() {
        List<Task> tasks = taskRepository.findAll();
        Assert.assertTrue(tasks.isEmpty());
    }
    
}
```

Any idea how I can instruct spring to generate that schema based on schema-it.sql content and then populated it with the data-it.sql data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@Sql` annotation which provide's way to populate database from .sql files when performing tests. U should use it as in following snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@SpringBootTest
@Sql({"/schema-it.sql", "/schema-it.sql"})
public class TaskRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetTasks() {
        List<Task> tasks = taskRepository.findAll();
        Assert.assertTrue(tasks.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will be run for each test. I need something to be run once during test initialization

Comment: Do you mean for each Test class method or for each Test class ??

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. The issues was with the .sql file names.

```
schema: classpath:schema-it.sql
data: classpath:data-it.sql
```

The correct names should have been:

```
schema: classpath:schema-postgresql.sql
data: classpath:data-postgresql.sql
```

Because platform is set to postgresql.